# Recursively Generate a Set of Every Possible Mapping between two Lists (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, recursion

**The Problem**

I am trying to write a method that recursively generates, and returns, a set of all possible maps between elements from one given list to another.

For example, say I input an arraylist of integers and an arraylist of strings.

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
integers.add(1); integers.add(2);

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("a"); strings.add("b"); strings.add("c");

combinations(integers, strings);
```

This should return the set containing all the following maps from integers to strings.

```
{
 (1 -> "a", 2 -> "b"), 
 (1 -> "a", 2 -> "c"),
 (1 -> "b", 2 -> "a"),
 (1 -> "b", 2 -> "c"),
 (1 -> "c", 2 -> "a"),
 (1 -> "c", 2 -> "b")
}
```

Here, each string (value) can only be mapped to one integer (key). In other words, no two integers can be mapped to the same string.

**Disclaimer and Specification**

Full discretion: this is a simplified version of the specification of one of the methods for a homework assignment -- and thus the method signature should look like this

```
Set<Map<Integer, String>> combinations(List<Integer> integers, List<String> strings);
```

and it must be written using recursion. Here it is assumed that the size of  `integers` is smaller than or equal to the size of `strings`. I will share what I have so far and explain why it isn't working and I need help.

**My Attempt (So far!)**

```
public static Set<Map<Integer, String>> combinations(
        List<Integer> integers, List<String> strings) {

    // Return set: The set of all possible mappings from integers -> strings
    Set<Map<Integer, String>> result = new HashSet<>();

    /* Base case: integers is empty => return the empty map.
       NOTE: It is assumed that there are fewer integers than strings. */
    if (integers.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(new HashMap<>());
        return result;
    }

    /* Recursive case: integers is non-empty =>
    *  get the first integer (call it "first") in integers and map it to any
    *  string (call it string) in strings.
    *  Recursively calculate all the mappings from the "rest of integers"
    *  (integers without "first") to the "rest of strings" (strings without
    *  "string").*/
    Integer first = integers.get(0);
    for (String string: strings) {
        Map<Integer, String> thisMap = new HashMap<>();
        thisMap.put(first, string);

        integers.remove(first);
        strings.remove(string);

        result = combinations(integers, strings);
        result.add(thisMap);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Here the output is just

```
{
 (),
 (1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
}
```

which is just a set containing the empty map and the first possible map.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why does `a-a`, `b-b` etc. not appear?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you mean why doesn't, for example, the map
    (1 -> "a", 2 -> "a")
appear, then that is because I mentioned no two integers can be mapped to the same string.
If you mean why doesn't, for example, the map
    ("a" -> "a", "b" -> "b")
appear, then that is because it is a set of maps from integers to strings. :)

Comment: @JacobG. Thanks! I'll await eagerly for your reply! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just providing the code, let me give pseudo code to give you an idea of how to do it. Then I suggest you try again and come back if you have any questions:

```
combinations(keys, values):
    create result set
    for each key in keys
        for each value in values
            combos = combinations(keys without key, values without value)
            for each combo
                add map from key -> value to combo
                add combo to result set
    return result set
```

*Update*

Now that OP has accepted this answer, here's working code to demonstrate the algorithm:

```
Set<Map<Integer, String>> combinations(List<Integer> keys, List<String> values) {
    if (keys.isEmpty())
        return Collections.singleton(new HashMap<>());
    else
        return keys.stream().flatMap(k -> 
            values.stream().flatMap(v -> 
                combinations(listWithout(keys, k), listWithout(values, v)).stream()
                    .peek(c -> c.put(k, v)))).collect(toSet());
}

private <T> List<T> listWithout (List<T> input, T value) {
    return input.stream().filter(v -> !v.equals(value)).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go and report back soon.

Comment: @TristanBatchler That's good. I'll add a solution to the answer for future readers' interest.